# Distinction between mechanics and thermodynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, terminology, definition

I claim to be able to put the distinction between mechanics and thermodynamics as follows:

> "In mechanics, energy is related to mass, whereas in thermodynamics, energy is related to a particle or to a quantity of particles."

Since I have not found this simple and clear formulation anywhere so far, I wonder if there is something wrong with it and would appreciate constructive feedback.

Clarification for better understanding: This statement only applies to the field of classical physics.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That statement doesn't really make sense.   Mechanics is the study of behavior of macro objects.  Thermodynamics, an archaic term for "statistical mechanics," is the study of energy & momentum behavior of large collections of (typically) small objects such as molecules in a fluid or a macro object.

Comment: I don't know what *either* of those statements means.  In what way is energy related to mass in mechanics? What does it mean to say that energy is "related to a particle" in thermodynamics?

Comment: @J.Murray  In classical mechanics,  $E = \frac{m*v^2}{2}$ .  In relativistic mechanics,  $E = \dot{\bf{p}}$ .   In StatMech (not "thermodynamics") ,  We look at the internal energy of the object, which is based on log(entropy) and all that stuff.  $T = \frac{1}{\frac{\delta S}{\delta U}}$

Comment: In order to avoid misinterpretation of my statement, I have narrowed it down, because it only refers to the field of classical physics. I hope it is clearer and that I will get some inspiring answers.

Answer (score 1):

Thermodynamics is mostly mechanics applied statistically to a large number of particles at equilibrium. It isn't an easy or short process, but that's the gist of it.

Saying that, in mechanics, energy is related to mass is incorrect. Even when remaining in "pure, macroscopic" mechanics (no thermic process, for instance), there are many forms of energy, and not all of them involve mass. Hooke law, for example.

Saying that, in thermodynamics, energy is related to a group of particles could be, technically, correct, but absolutely not a characteristic of thermodynamics. You can study many-body systems in mechanics. The point of thermodynamics is to "integrate out" the microscopic details to get statistical, "almost certainly true" properties at equilibrium (state parameters).

It'd be probably better to say that mechanics is the general study of dynamics due to interactions between systems, which is why you get one form of mechanics or another at the root of mostly everything (whether it be classical mechanics, quantum mechanics or relativistic mechanics).